# Why is the $p$-value significant but the confidence interval includes zero in a $t$-test?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, t-test, p-value

I am interested in learning whether the two groups below are statistically significant:

```
ex0112 = (
   BP       Diet
1   8    FishOil
2  13    FishOil
3  10    FishOil
4  14    FishOil
5   2    FishOil
6   1    FishOil
7   0    FishOil
8  -6 RegularOil
9   1 RegularOil
10  1 RegularOil
11  2 RegularOil
12 -3 RegularOil
13 -4 RegularOil
14  3 RegularOil
```

I run the following t-test:

```
t.test(BP ~ Diet, data = ex0112, conf.level = 0.99)
```

The results are:

```
    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  BP by Diet
t = 3.0109, df = 9.7071, p-value = 0.01352
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means between group FishOil and group RegularOil is not equal to 0
99 percent confidence interval:
 -0.4610773 15.8896488
sample estimates:
   mean in group FishOil mean in group RegularOil 
               6.8571429               -0.8571429
```

As you can see, the p-value for this test is

```
p-value = 0.014
```

which is significant at .05, but the confidence interval is

```
99 percent confidence interval:
 -0.4610773 15.8896488
```

which includes zero, and hence makes the difference between the groups insignificant. How can this be explained?

Comment: Why would you expect that a **99%** CI (i.e.e $1-\alpha=0.99; \alpha=0.01$) would correspond to a **5%** ($\alpha=0.05$) test??

Comment: The part I got wrong was that once I set the conf.level = .99, the p value will change to .01 automatically, and if it is not significant, p value would be above it. Obviously I wasn't thinking clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calculating a $99\,\%$-confidence interval. If you decided on a significance level of $0.01$, you would not reject the null hypothesis based on the $p$-value, because it's larger than $0.01$. If you want to use a significance level of $0.05$, corresponding to a $95\,\%$-confidence interval, specify `conf.level = 0.95`:

```R
dat <- data.frame(
  BP = c(8, 13, 10, 14, 2, 1, 0, -6, 1, 1, 2, -3, -4, 3)
  , Diet = rep(c("FishOil", "RegularOil"), each = 7)
)

t.test(BP~Diet, data = dat, conf.level = 0.95)

data:  BP by Diet
t = 3.0109, df = 9.7071, p-value = 0.01352
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means between group FishOil and group RegularOil is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  1.98202 13.44655
sample estimates:
   mean in group FishOil mean in group RegularOil 
               6.8571429               -0.8571429
```

The $95\,\%$-confidence interval $(1.98; 13.45)$ does not include $0$, as expected.